# Data structure design for event ordering

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

I'm working on a small system and I came up with an initial design/solution for the problem I'm just about to discribe. It is working, however I don't feel that it's the most elegant design for this problem, therefore I would be thankfull if you suggested how would you model such problem in terms of data structures:

- There is a concept of result and a series of events that lead to that result.
- Events are ordered according to their occurance order, they have no timestamps, only a position/index.
- Events order is not strict. Events possibly could happen in a different order as listed in the input.
- There are events that depend on the outcome of other events and that gives us a guarantee that their relative order is preserved. (For example: if we have 4 events in this order: A, B, C, D and events A & C are dependant, then there could be no variation in which C comes before A).

The most-common scenario in which I will use this data structure is to determine the range in which an event could possibly have occured, considering the dependecies described above.

example:

```
- Event A<------+
- Event B <---+ | D2
- Event C <---|-|----+
- Event D ----+-+    |
- Event E <---|------+
- Event F ----+D1    |
- Event G -----------+ D3
```

- D1 describes a dependency between F and B. F will never happen before B.
- D2 describes a dependency between D and A. D will never happen before A.
- D3 describes a dependency between G and E and C. G will never happen before either E or C.

And I would like to traverse this collection and on each element get the range in which that event could possibly have happened given that other elements order reamin constant. This is the simple version.

For v.2.0 I will need the possible range of the current element's order given that others might move as well. I.e in which combination event X is as close to the beginning as possible, or Y is as close to the end as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing can be modeled by a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), in which each node represents some event an edge from u to v means that u has to come before v.

Given this representation, I believe that you can efficiently (in time O(n + m), where n is the number of events and m the number of contraints) determine the latest possible time at which some event could occur by using a modified [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  Specifically, begin doing a standard topological sort of the nodes, but whenever you would expand out the node representing the event in question, instead skip it and expand out other nodes instead (in other words, pick a different source node).  When you have completely exhausted other nodes to expand, then you will be left with a DAG in which there is only one source node, namely the node that you want to expand out.  The nodes that you have previously expanded are thus the events that could potentially occur before the event you're curious about, so you can get its latest possible position by seeing how many events come before it.

As an optimization, if you have a fixed structure (you don't add any events or dependencies), you can precompute this information by counting up how many descendant nodes each node in the DAG has.  The number of descendants of the node is the number of nodes that cannot possibly by positioned before it in any topologically sorted order, and this information can be computed once in time O(n + m).  Once you've cached this, the last possible position for each element is n - 1 - k, where k is the number of descendants of that node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @aelguindy- I'm not sure I see how it would output 4.  In a topological sort when the node was always skipped whenever possible, it would always be expanded last.  Remember that a topological sort is not the same as a depth-first search; you can jump around the graph randomly, picking source nodes and removing them regardless of what the last node you removed was.  Am I incorrect about this?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I got confused. So sorry! It seems my vote is locked now :(.

Comment: @aelguindy- No worries!  I have edited the answer in case you want to remove the downvote.  But thanks for pointing this out; it's an important detail!